# Using anonymous function as property getter/setter

Tags: properties, anonymous-function, haxe

The following code gives a compilation error:

```
public var x(function(){return 2}, never) : Int;
```

Is there a way to make such constructions in haxe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some days ago same topic discussed on haxe google group.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/haxelang/jmpjNGdGFYI/byvc84WpDgoJ